# Accessing machine connected to another machine

Tags: windows-7, lan

I have very simple network with 3 machines on it:

- **A** - Asus router
- **B** - Windows 7 PC with two network cards
- **C** - LG Smart TV

**A** is connected to the internet over WAN port, and **B** is connected to the **A** over LAN port, and **C** is connected to the **B** over separate cable because **B** has to network adapters. I can not connect **C** directly to **A**, but I need **C** to be accessible from **A** or any other device connected to **A**.

Here is a diagram:

[image: diagram]

Please keep in mind that **I can not and do not want to change the network layout**, I just need to access **C** on the network as it is. I can change all the settings though, all the software related stuff, just not the hardware, so no additional adapters, no physical bridges or similar stuff.

Some additional information on how it is configured at the moment:

- On **B** first adapter is configured to obtain an IP address
  automatically, and on **A** there is a DHCP rule to assign
  192.168.1.2 to it.
- Second adapter is configured manually, IP 192.168.2.1, subnet mask
  255.255.255.0, gateway and DNS are empty.
- On **C** adapter is also configured manually, but here gateway and
  DNS are required, so IP 192.168.2.2, subnet mast 255.255.255.0,
  gateway 192.168.2.1, DNS 8.8.8.8.
- If I enable Internet Connection Sharing on **B** first adapter, **C**
  has internet access, but is not accessible from **A**.

I am not very educated on networking, and have been searching for solution for a week now with no luck.

---

[Tetsujin suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/861663/accessing-machine-connected-to-another-machine?noredirect=1#comment1143470_861663) to try bridging the adapters on **B** as [explained by William Hilsum](https://superuser.com/a/257082/395923) on another [similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/257075/routing-internet-through-ethernet-to-a-computer-without-a-wireless-adapter), so I did. But after bridging **C** isn't able to connect to the gateway I set up before bridging, and I can not access **C** from **B** anymore, when before bridging I was able to ping 192.168.2.2. I tried rebooting bot **B** and **C** after bridging, tried obtaining IP on **C** on auto, no luck.

Maybe I need a *crossover* cable for that? But ICS works with regular cable... I will try that anyway in a few days because I am out of options anyway...

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7

Comment: ICS is not enough, I need to access the TV from within the network, for example to use remote control app, it can not access it when remote is connected to router and TV is connected to the PC.

Comment: then you may need to raise your 'can & do not want to change the network' clause, unless you want to turn B into a fully-fledged gateway. The simplest method of all would be stick a switch in just before B & wire it all to that.

Comment: _Fully-fledged gateway_ works for me, though I am not sure I fully understand what does it mean, and I definitely do not know how to do that, so if someone could give me a link of a tutorial or write a step by step guide I'd be super grateful.

Comment: see if this helps - http://superuser.com/questions/257075/routing-internet-through-ethernet-to-a-computer-without-a-wireless-adapter

Comment: After bridging **C** isn't able to connect to the gateway I set up before bridging, and I can not access **C** from **B** anymore, when before bridging I was able to ping 192.168.2.2. I tried rebooting bot **B** and **C** after bridging, tried obtaining IP on **C** on auto, no luck.

Maybe I need a *crossover* cable for that? But ICS works with regular cable... I will try that anyway in a few days, because I am out of options...

Comment: So I tried the crossover cable, still no luck, same result as with regular cable...

Comment: Yeah, modern machines are smart enough to figure that out. I think you're shooting a housefly with an elephant gun anyway. Just get a switch.